# Marketplace in Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm just wondering if there is a way to download some apps for the emulator. The thing is that we're about to start our own application and we want to make sure we're doing everything 'Windows Phone 7 Compliant'. I want to go through some apps and see what / how they do stuff; like going to the settings, animations, navigations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is correct, there's no marketplace access in the emulator.

The best thing you could do to check compliance of your app is to review the [UI Design Guidelines](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/7365b3c6-9fdc-48fe-bf17-192c71f2a49f) and [App Certification Requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did find a hacky way to supposedly get into the market, but I don't really want to try it, so I guess I'll stick with this. Thanks!

Comment: Aye, I always consider mentioning that, but I'm wary of publicly recommending execution of unoffical code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't today.  You can check out design guidelines at [developer.windowsphone.com](http://developer.windowsphone.com).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that, you will not able to donwload app there, but this code will help to see MarketPlace on the Emulator.

Create a Sample Console App, Add Reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\microsoft shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\10.0\Bin\Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll 
In the main method paste following code.

```
DatastoreManager datastoreManager = new DatastoreManager(1033);
Platform platform = datastoreManager.GetPlatforms().Single(p => p.Name == "Windows Phone 7");
Device device = platform.GetDevices().Single(d => d.Name == "Windows Phone Emulator");
device.Connect();
Guid appID = new Guid("{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5630}");
if (device.IsApplicationInstalled(appID))
{
    RemoteApplication app = device.GetApplication(appID);
    app.Launch();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I got the appid by using ILSPy for Windows Phone Library.
Links which helped me.

- http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-launch-marketplace-in-windows.html
- http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 devices have started appearing in the market. You should plan to get hold of one. I have done most of my Windows Phone 7 app development using the emulator. When I got my hands on a device few weeks ago, I started testing testing the apps and found a number of issues related to performance, network connectivity, etc. Therefore, it is really beneficial to test applications on a real device before submitting to the Marketplace.

Comment: Just a mention on this note, Telstra go live today at 12:00 with WP7 product launch in Australia. This should be happening around Europe and Asia/Pacific.

Comment: Confirmed, http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2010/10/20/the-windows-phone-7-launch-has-started.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was initially targeting Windows Phone 7, it might be interesting to other visitors to know that the WP8 emulator does have marketplace access.

Comment: How do you sign in and download apps? I get the "Problem signing in" 0x8000FFFF error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198614/is-it-possible-to-sign-into-a-microsoft-account-with-the-windows-8-phone-emulato

Comment: You can't sign in; it just lists apps and lets you browse them, but you can't download.

Comment: Ok. Marketplace is view accessible but not fully functional.