# Is it possible to sign into a Microsoft Account with the Windows 8 Phone emulator?

Tags: onedrive, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I recently tried to sign into my Microsoft Account to test out some features which require it(Skydrive, Store, lots of other things). However, when I try to sign in and such I get this error:

"We've run into a problem signing in.... 0x8000FFFF"

[image]

Is it just unsupported? How do you test things such as the [Skydrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310) without having a physical Windows 8 phone?

Comment: I tried logging into the marketplace too, but I got the same error in Windows Phone SDKs 7.1, 7.8, and 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sadly not possible on the public released SDK. It was previous possible in the pre-released versions of the SDK, and during the closed public beta.

Comment: How? I have internet access on the phone and everything, but no matter what I enter at the sign in thing (valid or invalid credentials), I just get that generic error

Comment: It's been working fine for me since May, so I don't see why it fails for you.

Comment: I recall it working some time ago with a pre-release version, but no matter what I do I just get that error message now

Comment: I can double check that it's still meant to be possible when I get in the office on Monday.

Comment: Ok, I'd find it hard to believe if they didn't make it possible with all the APIs that require it, but the error message is always there

Comment: Would be strange indeed, given that it's been working most of 2012 ;-) Then again, most of us have several devices already for testing, so nobody paid it much attention lately.

Comment: This [forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1967187) appears to indicate it's not possible... which basically means if you intend to do development on Windows Phone 8 you have to buy a phone if you want to do anything more than hello world samples

Comment: Not true. The Skype client for WP8 runs fully in the emulator.

Comment: I would test that, but I have to sign in to download from the store :P And I mean there are quite a few APIs that require signing in, the big one being SkyDrive. I had an app with that API in mind, but I'm not going to put $500 on a new Windows 8 phone

Comment: You shouldn't publish apps without having tested them on a real device first regardless...